# convert tiff file to pdf using img2pdf

Tags: python, image, pdf, tiff

I need to crawl into folders and subfolders, identify tiff file that doesn't have a pdf version and create a new one if necessary. Unfortunately, it does not work for all tiff. I am wondering how to keep going if the conversion does not happen.

```
def makePDF(path, filename, image_files):
    output_file = path + '/' + filename + ".pdf"
    try:
        with open(output_file,"wb") as f:
           f.write(img2pdf.convert(image_files))         
           #f.close()        
    except IOError as error:
        print ('opss')
        pass
```

Comment: You mean your `try..except` error handling does not handle your errors, other than `IOError`? So what else did you get?

Comment: Exactly, the script stops without retrieving any error. Any suggestions on how to catch an error?

Comment: That seems to indicate `img2pdf.convert` at least *thinks* it worked. Better be sure: run your code without the `try..except` and see if it only throws the "expected" errors. If it does, the error lies deeper inside `imgpdf`. Rewrite your code to a [mcve]; it is not immediately clear to me where this `img2pdf.convert` function came from.